Remove synonym [yarn] -> [hadoop-yarn]
There are two major software products that use "yarn" in their names:

Hadoop YARN (hadoop-yarn) - Hadoop is a distributed computing platform and YARN is a resource manager and scheduler for user applications running in Hadoop.
Yarn yarnpkg - a package manager for Node.js code bases.

There used to be a tag called yarn which was ambiguous between the two technologies. From Disentangle the [yarn]! this ambiguous tag was made synonym of hadoop-yarn which means there were a lot of questions about Node.js applications tagged as if using Hadoop YARN when they were not using Hadoop at all.
I have been monitoring the tag* since and we still get a steady trickle of those. Presumably people are typing in "yarn" in the tags:

because they have some question related to the only "Yarn" they know - the package manager. Then upon publishing that gets substituted for the Hadoop-related tag.
* more specifically I made a custom filter for [hadoop-yarn] -[hadoop] -[apache-pig] -[cluster-computing] -[apache-spark] -[hadoop2] -[mapreduce] -[apache-twill] -[oozie] -[apache-apex] -[apache-flink] (query) to focus on items that are mostly not Hadoop related.

I propose the synonym is dropped. There was confusion before but a synonym does not resolve that confusion. Just deepens it because users do not even have the forewarning they are not using the tag they think they are using.
There does not seem to be any existing usages of yarn. So, once the synonym is dropped, the tag should be automatically cleaned up. For the moment, I do not see a need for a blocklist - the usage of ambiguous tag is ambiguous. If the tag does get recreated again and again perhaps a blocklist would be warranted.

"From Disentangle the [yarn]! this ambiguous tag was made synonym of hadoop-yarn" the classic, lets make the ambiguous tag synonym to one of the terms. When confronted with a ambiguous tag, there's no solution other than complete removal. They can't exists.
